# Access the host's cmd remotely from external address using ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd.exe

after installing Openssh, I can access to the ubuntu's cmd using ssh from and a linux OS or a windows (using putty) and not only locally but using a wan address(public). 
 My question is : what should i do to access the windows's cmd from an other windows's cmd not locally but with a wan address (public) using ssh ?
I now that i can use telnet but here i want to use SSH. 
 
 Here's what a have : 
 - I installed a software from noip.com that will give my computer's ip a name even if it is a dynamic ip. 
- And obviously when i tape the http://mycomputer-hostname.com (which refers to my computer) in putty from an other computer through internet not locally, i got a popup window says login and password and when i enter those two, putty login into the router's cmd. i understand that i need to install something equivalent to Openssh but it's not supported on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Though Microsoft does not currently provide SSH server software for its Windows operating system, there are quite a few commercial SSH server packages available for Windows and there is also free SSH server software, some of which does rely on a Windows implementation of OpenSSH. Some companies that provide commercial versions will allow you to use their software for free for noncommercial use. Some free versions that I've used:

[Bitvise SSH Server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-download) - free for personal use

[Copssh](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/ssh/Copssh501/) - [the name is from "Cygwin" + "OpenSSH"](https://www.itefix.net/content/why-it-called-copssh)

[freeSSHd](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/network/ssh/freeSSHd/)

[OpenSSH for Windows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/) - the software hasn't been updated since, 2004. I found it worked well on Windows XP systems, but I've experiencd problems with it on later versions of Windows and I wouldn't recommend it.

[PowerShell SSH Server for Windows](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/ssh/PSSrvr6/) - the Personal Edition is free; it limits you to one SSH connection to the server at a time.

[SilverSHield](http://www.extenua.com/silver-shield.html) - [free for personal use version limited to one concurrent SSH connection](http://www.extenua.com/SilverShieldpricing.jpg)

Alternatively, you can install [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), which provides a Unix-like environment and command-line interface for Microsoft Windows, and then [install OpenSSH server software for Cygwin](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/).

Microsoft has has announced that it intends to provide SSH server software for its Windows operating systems, e.g., see the June 2, 2015 Ars Technica article [Microsoft bringing SSH to Windows and PowerShell](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/06/microsoft-bringing-ssh-to-windows-and-powershell/), but it may be awhile before that software is available.

After you've installed SSH server software on the Microsoft Windows system, if you have host-based firewall software on the system, such as Microsoft's firewall software or firewall software that may be part of an antivirus program, you may need to set up an appropriate firewall rule to allow inbound connections for the SSH server, either allowing inbound traffic to the SSH server application or to TCP port 22, if you use the standard port. You may also need to set up an appropriate firewall rule and/or port forwarding on a router/firewall you have in front of the Microsoft Windows system.